# Woocommerce Custom CSV export

Tags: php, plugins

I've been trying to figure this out for the past few days.

Is there a plugin that exports CSV with the Order Items all on the same line but not in the same column cell?

Example: Item Name_01, Item Quantity_01, Item Variation_01, Item Amount_01, Item Total Price_01, Item Name_02, Item Quantity_02, Item Variation_02, Item Amount_02, Item Total Price_02

I purchased the WooComerce Exporter and it doesn't have that ability. It's either ONLY all products in one column OR all products listed on their own row.

I'm told that neither of these options are able to be imported into my organizations database because the importer cannot accurately map the values (doesn't make sense to me, but that's what I'm told)

Any help would be great. Whether it's an update to this plugin that I already purchased, or if it's a new plugin, or tips on modifying the plugin.

I don't want to spend needless hours if something like this already exists.

Comment: Did you mean you tried to purchase this plugin --> http://www.visser.com.au/woocommerce/plugins/exporter/ ? its actually free...

Answer (score 1):

Ain't this just a matter of opening the exported CSV with *all products on their own row* and doing a global search/replace of "`carriage returns`" for "`commas`"?

This way you get the format in your example...

> Example: Item Name_01, Item Quantity_01, Item Variation_01, Item Amount_01, Item Total Price_01, Item Name_02, Item Quantity_02, Item Variation_02, Item Amount_02, Item Total Price_02